# Question on polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is a question from Hoffman:

If $F$ is a field and $h$ is a polynomial over $F$ of degree $\ge 1$, show that the mapping $f \rightarrow f(h) $ is a one-one linear transformation of $F[x]$ into $F[x]$. Show that this transformation is an isomorphism of $F[x]$ onto $F[x]$ if and only if deg $h = 1$.

I believe that the first part is easy. To show that the mapping $f \rightarrow f(h) $ is a one-one linear transformation of $F[x]$ into $F[x]$, we need to show that if $f(h) = 0 $, then $f=0$.

Suppose $f(h) = 0 $. Since $h$ is a polynomial of degree $\ge 1$ and since $f(h)=0$, $f$ must be equal to $0$.

The second part is the part I don't understand. To show that it is an isomorphism, we need to show that

1) It is one-one (already shown)

2) Show that the linear structure is preserved. (Easy to show)

3) Show that the transformation is onto.

I don't see how condition 3 can be fulfilled because when deg $h=1$, $fh$ can never be mapped to a polynomial with degree $<1$ in $F[x]$ (e.g. $f=cx^0$, where $c$ is a scalar in the field $F$)

Comment: I can't see how you think you already **proved** injectivity just by stating "Since $h$ is a polynomial of degree $\ge 1$ and since $f(h)=0$, $f$ must be equal to $0$" ...?

Comment: I initially thought that $fh=f(h)$. We know that if $f$ and $h$ are non-zero polynomials, then $fh$ is also a non-zero polynomial. Therefore, if $fh=0$ and $h \neq 0$, then $f=0$. But it seems that $fh \neq f(h)$, so my "prove" is wrong.

Comment: Where *exactly* is that question in Hoffmann's book, please?

Comment: The exact question, word for word, is:

Comment: If $F$ is a field and $h$ is a polynomial over $F$ of degree $\ge 1$, show that the mapping $f \rightarrow f(h) $ is a one-one linear transformation of $F[x]$ into $F[x]$. Show that this transformation is an isomorphism of $F[x]$ onto $F[x]$ if and only if deg $h = 1$.

Comment: Then that seems to be composition of polynomials = what you did, I think.

Comment: But that will mean that the transformation is not surjective, since no polynomial composing with a deg $1$ polynomial $h$ can give a 0-polynomial (i.e. $fg=cx^0$)

Comment: Well, the constant polynomials work fine for that, don't they @user102484 ? For example, if $\;f(x):=c\;,\;\;h(x)=ax+b\;$ , then $$f(h(x))=f(ax+b)=c\ldots$$

Comment: Yeah, that will work if we consider $f(h)$ to be a composition and not a product. My "prove" above for injectivity only works for products and not compositions. Can you prove that if $f(h)=0$, then $f=0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=c$ then $f(h)=c$ also.

**Addendum:** If $h$ has degree $1$, $h(x)=ax+b$ then the mapping is surjective: every $g(x)$ has a preimage $f(x)=g(\frac{x-b}{a})$.

Further, let $f(x)=c_nx^n+\ldots +c_0, \ c_n\ne 0$. If $f(ax+b)=0$ then  the leading coefficient $c_na^n$ must be equal to $0$. This is impossible, so $f=0$ and the mapping is injective.

Comment: If $f(x)=c$, it means that $f$ has deg $<1$ right? Then $fg$ will have deg $=1$ right?

Comment: No, $\deg fh =0$. You have to substitute $h$ instead of $x$, but $x$ is absent!

Comment: Oh ok... so $f(h) \neq fh$ ?

Comment: I read that the definition of $fh$ is that $(fh)_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}f_ih_{n-i}$ Suppose deg $h=1$ and deg $f<1$, then $h_1 \neq 0$. Hence $(fh)_1 \neq 0$. But if we sub $h$ into $f$ in $f(h)$, then $(f(h))_1 = 0$.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that $f \rightarrow f(h)$ is not a one-one linear transformation since even when $f(h) = 0$, $f$ might not be $0$, since it can be a scalar polynomial (i.e. anything of the form $cx^0$) ?

Comment: First of all let's agree on the notation. In your question you use $f(h)$ and $fh$. Is this the same?

Comment: In the original question only $f(h)$ is present. I initially thought that $f(h)=fh$ and therefore I used them interchangeably. There is no $fh$ in the original question.

Comment: Hmm, so are they the same?

Comment: It depends on what you mean. I think you have to consider only $f(h)$, not $(fh)_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}f_ih_{n-i}$.

Comment: I wanted to consider the $n$th component of $fh$ because I wanted to try to see what the degree of $fh$ is when deg $h=1$. It seems that when deg $h=1$ and $f \neq 0$, deg $fh=1$ since the $n$th component is $\neq 0$. Therefore, $ f \rightarrow fh $ cannot be onto. This led me to believe that $fh \neq f(h)$ because if the question is right, the transformation must be onto. However, if we use the $f(h)$ understanding, the transformation won't be one-one. So I am now a little confused...

Comment: You have to consider $f(h)$. The transformation is surjective (see Addendum in the answer).

Comment: Is there a good way to prove that the transformation of $f \rightarrow f(h)$ is injective? I know that to do that we need to show that if $f(h)=0$, then $f=0$. How do we proceed?

Comment: Again see the answer.

Comment: Is there a theorem to prove that if $f(y)=0$  for all $y$, then $f\equiv 0$? It seems intuitive but I don't think it can be taken for granted that it is true. For example, in the case of dual spaces, given a vector space $V$ and a subspace of $V$ called $W$, there are non-zero linear functionals $f$ that maps all elements in $W$ to $0$.

Comment: This follows from the fact that a non-zero polynomial has only finite number of roots.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Thanks for the time professor:) By the way is there an important difference between a polynomial and a polynomial function?

Comment: Yes, it is for fields of non-zero characteristic (e.g., the polynomial $x^2-1$ in the field $\mathbb{F_2}$). Apropos, sorry, my last comment is not true for such fields. I will change the answer.